# Exit conditions for France for dual French-Tunisian citizen

Tags: france, dual-nationality

Can a person with a french passport and a **tunisian passport**

Go from Paris to Tunisia.

To visit family. I'm reading the below and am really scared.

https://www.diplomatie.gouv.fr/fr/le-ministere-et-son-reseau/actualites-du-ministere/informations-coronavirus-covid-19/coronavirus-declarations-et-communiques/article/communique-assouplissement-des-conditions-d-entree-et-de-sortie-du-territoire

Comment: Can you please write, in a few lines in English, what is in that site behind the link? As it is now we would have to open the link to understand what the question is about and that is only working as long as the site is there. And that is against the rules here.

Comment: The link seems to say two things: a) that restrictions on travel between France and a given list of countries (but not Tunisia) have been eased, and b) that the definition of a "compelling reason to travel" has been widened. It also contains a list of links to previous official travel advice. What is it that is scaring you?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over